# Load environment variables without enabling load user profile?

Tags: .net, windows, iis, environment-variables

I have an IIS application that runs using an app pool where we need to set a specific user for granting access to network resources.
Now we also use the environment configuration builder in dotnet to override our settings for each of our environments.

However.. I have noticed that for the variables to even load, we need to enable "LoadUserProfile" for app pool. Is there a way to load variables without setting this? From my understanding this loads the **user profile**. But cant environment variables be set to "machine"-scope, which I guess wouldnt be bound to a specific user?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want IIS to load environment variables from user profiles, then you have to explicitly define them in IIS configuration, as part of the application pool settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/environmentvariables/